# dataset of workout/bodybuilding QA

Tags: data-request, sports

I am looking for a dataset of bodybuilding/workout/exercise Q&A in a machine-readable way.

For example:
Q: What kinds of exercises to train my chest at home?
A: Push up. (or any article, website)

Q: How to do the deadlift?
A: There are 3 different way to do the ...